# USB female type A that "floats" on a PCB

Tags: usb, connector

I'm looking for a USB-connector that "floats" in line with the PCB. See my very crude drawing to see what I mean:

[image]

I know these connectors exists for USB micro (like [this one](https://www.tme.eu/se/en/details/mx-47491-0001/usb-ieee1394-connectors/molex/47491-0001/)) but I am unable to find it for type A-female.

Do they exist, and what search terms should I use to find this type of connector?

Comment: Search for offset USB connectors.

Comment: Sometimes known as "Sinking board type".

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called a "mid mount" connector. They exist in the type A receptacle but will most likely be the USB 3.0 type instead of the 4-pin USB 2.0 type that you are probably thinking about. I used a search phrase of "mid mount USB Type A connector" and found several suitable styles.

Any mid mount connector that you choose to use should have metal shell fingers that sit on pads on the surface of the circuit board that get soldered to secure the connector. Something just mounted by four leads as you made in your picture will not standup to use of the large Type A plug that would mate with it.

Answer (score 2):

Molex has two mid-mount connectors: [482580001](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0482580001_IO_CONNECTORS.xml) and [482580002](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0482580002_IO_CONNECTORS.xml).

You can find them on some online suppliers by searching for those product codes, or filtering/searching for "mid-mount" or "board cutout" type connectors.

[image: Image from the Digi-Key listing for the 482580001 connector]

> Universal Serial Bus (USB) Shielded I/O Receptacle, Type A, Right-Angle, Reverse Type, Mid Mount with Side Flange and Beveled Metal Pins, Gold (Au) Plated, Lead-Free

Image from the [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0482580001/WM6294TR-ND/2642182) listing for the 482580001 connector, description from Molex site.

Answer (score 0):

here you are: [link to the usb-con you need :)](https://www.tme.eu/se/en/details/usba-go3.0_smd/usb-ieee1394-connectors/ninigi/)

How I found it:
- On the same site on which you found the micro-USB (www.tme.eu), I went to the USB-connector cathalog [link to the usb connectors](https://www.tme.eu/se/en/katalog/usb-ieee1394-connectors_100379/)
- As "type of connector", I selected "USB-A"
- As "Mechanical Mounting", I selected "on PCBs"
- As "Electrical mounting", I selected "SMD"
- As "Connector", I selected "Socket" (for female)

The one I found was the 6th result.

Comment: Answers that are just a link to another site are discouraged here, because the links often break and make the answer useless. We also try to avoid recommending specific products or places to buy them. It would be better to just tell the OP what search terms to use and leave it at that.

Comment: Changed my solution